# AWS ECS Containers and External DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

- We have AWS ECS instances.
- We're using an external service (Twilio) that needs to reach a specific container:port.
- And it's SSL, so it has to be a DNS name

Currently, our Upgrade scripts assigns each container an entry in Route53, and I can use a combination of nslookup and my external IP address to discover my name (and then set an env var) on bootup.

But if containers crash, my upgrade script won't have run, so updating Route 53 won't have happened.

Is this problem already solved in some way? At this point, I'm looking at 2 or 3 days to implement a solution.

I don't believe I can use Service Discovery, as SD uses the internal IP address and would be in foo.local, which isn't externally accessible.

At this point, I think I have to write a program that determines what my DNS name needs to be and updates Route 53. That seems simple, but I also have to add permissions to update Route 53 to the IAM user inside the container, and that sounds like a security problem. I'd write a different program to expire dead names.

Is there a better way? This doesn't seem like that unique a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this the problem that [ECS Services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_services.html) and their integration with AWS Load Balancers solve? If you have an ECS task that needs to run for a long time, and it needs to be accessible at a public address, then it needs to run in an ECS service that is configured to use a public load balancer.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that for other things. But do public load balancers work on non-http traffic? And how do I resolve to a SPECIFIC instance of my application running on a SPECIFIC container? That is, I have to go to the correct host and port.

Comment: You would use a Network Load Balancer for non-HTTP traffic. As for the specific instance thing, why does it need to work that way? That's typically not how scalable, fault-tolerant systems are designed. Are each of your container instances stateful?

Comment: It's a phone conversation. We effectively do a call to Twilio that says, "Make this phone call and talk to us on a websocket at foo.com:9999" (which is the same instance that initiated the phone call).

Comment: So to make that scalable I would store that initial call info in a database, and let Twilio call you over the load balancer, and whatever server gets the connection looks up the info in the DB when the call begins. Also note that Application Load Balancers do support Websockets.